# Convert decimal separator from ',' (comma) to '.' (dot) e.g. "7,5" to "7.5"

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

Yes. I know. Those are localization settings...

But I wont tell my client to change localization settings for just my app.

So how to convert those numbers? Or how to change number formatting for given range. (Need  dots there, user may input comas or dots, or even numbers where commas just separate like 1,000,000.00 ...)

EDIT:
Circumvented whole issue by CStr(), and passing on the strings.

Comment: This link may helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: That solve my problem partially. Now numbers are in deed "7.5" but.. "7,5" will be "7" in vba. :| How can I force user to input numbers with dots?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Please describe a typical scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is purely for display purposes then you can use custom format strings on the cells. Then your users can continue to use their localization settings that they are used to for inputting numbers. I think that changing localization settings would be a bad idea, as then your client may enter numbers incorrectly.

This is the general way of formatting numbers using custom format strings.

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ To display  ║            As            ║ Use this code ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1234.59     ║ 1234.6                   ║ ####.#        ║
║             ║                          ║               ║
║ 8.9         ║ 8.9                      ║ #.000         ║
║             ║                          ║               ║
║ 0.631       ║ 0.6                      ║ 0.#           ║
║             ║                          ║               ║
║ 12          ║ 12                       ║ #.0#          ║
║             ║                          ║               ║
║ 1234.568    ║ 1234.57                  ║ #.0#          ║
║             ║                          ║               ║
║ 44.398      ║   44.398                 ║ ???.???       ║
║ 102.65      ║ 102.65                   ║ ???.???       ║
║ 2.8         ║     2.8                  ║ ???.???       ║
║             ║ (with aligned decimals)  ║               ║
║             ║                          ║               ║
║ 5.25        ║ 5 1/4                    ║ # ???/???     ║
║ 5.3         ║ 5  3/10                  ║ # ???/???     ║
║             ║ (with aligned fractions) ║ # ???/???     ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

---

And here is a link to the Microsoft information on regional format strings

(updated link 11-aug-2016)

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

Comment: Tried this it does not works at all. 1234,56 needs to be displayed as 1234.56 just as the OP requested but using ####.## displays it as 1.234 which is not correct.

Comment: @GuidoG I don't know... I don't understand why 1234,56 would be displayed as 1.234. They're not even the same number..

Comment: So the code from the answer does not works. It still displays the . as a decimal separator and the , as a thousand separator.